# Fire validations on conditional

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I'm working on a validation rule that it validates on condition, so the condition is:

Is Active (isactive__c) must be `yes` if `not` then other__c cannot be null

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Activated'), 
AND(isactive__c = false,other__c == null), 
OR( 
$Profile.Name == "Super User" 
) 
)
```

Comment: It doesn't look from your formula that you provided in your explanations all conditions you want to have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will evaluate to true when:

1. IsActive__c == FALSE AND Other__c is blank

per your request

```
AND(isactive__c = false,ISBLANK(other__c))
```

OR (more correct)

```
AND(NOT(isactive__c),ISBLANK(other__c))
```

Now not sure what you want to do if Active__c == TRUE and you did not have in your question anything about a profile

Also, when you say **yes** do you mean **true** or is it literally **yes** as in `IsActive__c` is a *boolean* field

Comment: i will give it a shot, just curious to know can you use `== null` instead of isblank?

Comment: @NickKahn You can but ''  evaluates to false when comparing to null but does evaluate to true with isBlank. Also, always use the available functions when creating validation rules for consistent and documented behavior. SF still supports ISNULL but states to use ISBLANK instead of a null check